# Watch WCF activity like Com+

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm now switching from com+ to wcf.
One thing i see that wcf is missing is the ability to see how many objects are currently active, call time, and in call.
Is there a tool that will give me the same data for wcf?
I use IIS as host for my wcf services.

Thanks.

[image: Com+ activity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at WCF performance counters : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx

Launch perfmon.exe, and look at the categories :

- ServiceModelEndpoint
- ServiceModelService
- ServiceModelOperation